# Creating files breaks -DDEBUG flag in Makefile for C++

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, linker

In my Makefile I am using the -DDEBUG Flag for debugging which works fine (compiles and right output) in the following minimal example:

```
# Makefile
all : debug

CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-value
SOURCES = main.cpp vector.cpp
OBJECTS = $(subst .cpp,.o, $(SOURCES))

debug: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DDEBUG -o Program $(OBJECTS)
    ./Program

clean:
    rm *.o Program

.PHONY: clean debug
```

But when i copy all project-files into the Folder the Debug-Flag wont be set (tested with #ifdef DEBUG and cout). I am adding the following files:

```
ind.hpp ind.cpp debug.hpp debug.cpp
```

I first thought debug.* could be the problem, but ".PHONY: clean debug" didn't help.

Comment: You aren't building the object files with the `DEBUG` in that makefile. That isn't working the way you expect. You need that on the compilation line not the linking line. Add it to `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: BTW, the opposite convention of setting `NDEBUG` for non-debug forms (and not setting `NDEBUG`  when debugging!) is followed by [assert(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html)

Comment: Unless you really want to learn how to write a `Makefile`, I would suggest you use a tool to generate it. I like `cmake`. The old way is the `automake` (which is pretty terrible, if you ask me). There are others too. These would create the correct `Makefile` for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Makefile` change this:

```
debug: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DDEBUG -o Program $(OBJECTS)
```

to:

```
debug: $(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DDEBUG -o Program $(SOURCES)
```

The reason being that in the rule to build `debug` target you are just `linking` the object files and not `compiling` with `-DDEBUG`. With this change you should be able to compile with `-DDEBUG` flag.

Comment: Thanks, this works and seems logic. But i got two followup-questions: First: Why did it work in the first place, when the other files weren't there? And second: Why are many Makefile examples/tutorials suggesting something like "$(CC) -o prog $(OBJ)"?

Comment: Lastly, why creating "$(SOURCES)" if not using them. Thought this would be the cleaner way.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the first question `when the other files weren't there`? . To answer the second question-- It is because `Makefile` has a predefined set of auto rules, which will generate the object (*.o) files. Hence only linking the object files is needed.

Comment: You are using `$(SOURCES)` to generate the list of object files.